# graph query for object privacy settings returns empty set

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, privacy

I'm trying to access the privacy settings for the posts on my wall with an app that has been authorized to "read_stream". While I can (now) nicely retrieve the posts and comments both using the graph api directly and with fql I am confused by the fact that querying the fql "privacy" table for the object-privacy with -

https://graph.facebook.com//fql?q=SELECT+object_id%2C+value%2C+description%2C+allow%2C+deny%2C+owner_id%2C+networks%2C+friends+FROM+privacy+WHERE+object_id=[object_id]&access_token=[access_token]

- returns an empty set -

{
   "data": [

]
}

when the privacy setting for the respective posts is "custom". Similarly confusing, the direct graph api request for the same object fails to include the privacy property described in the description for the post object at -

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

as well as a number of other described object properties.

I truly hope that someone can explain what I don't understand and doing incorrectly, or if there's been undocumented changes to retrieving object privacy information.

Thanks!

Comment: you have double slashes in the url (https://graph.facebook.com//fql...)

Answer (score 0):

From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy/

> An FQL table that can be used to return a user's privacy setting for a
>   video, note, link, photo, or photo album that they published.

So according to their documentation, POST is not listed.

This returns [].  `SELECT id, value, description FROM privacy WHERE id IN (SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=me())`

However, if I query videos: `SELECT id, value, description FROM privacy WHERE id IN (SELECT vid FROM video WHERE owner=me())`, I get results.

I would presume looking at note, link, photo and photo album would behave normally.